# Rewrite URL using .htaccess call without directory name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really can't understand how to write htaccess lines. I was trying to Google for few hours and couldn't find anything relevant. Can anybody suggest me a simple .htaccess line that can let me navigate to `http://www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/index5.html`

by calling it as `http://www.mydomain.com/required`

I tried in the below manner but I didn't work for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^required    mydirectory/index5.html    [NC,L]
```

And, an other question if I place this .htaccess file in the mydirectory folder will that work or am I supposed to place this file only in the root folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in `.htaccess` in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^required/?$ /mydirectory/index5.html [NC,L]
```

**PS:** You cannot keep this code in `/mydirectory` since your original URI doesn't contain `/mydirectory`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: How about calling http://www.mydomain.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/index5.php with http://www.mydomain.com/required

Comment: Then rule will be: `RewriteRule ^required/?$ /directory1/directory2/directory3/index5.php [NC,L]`

Comment: I added these lines underneath the .htaccess lines in the public_html folder.

Comment: Started working when I tried this example `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   horses.htm   Xu8JuefAtua.htm` but page is loading and unable to load css files.

Comment: For css, js files make sure to use absolute paths i.e. ones starting with `http://` or `/`